# OpenCV 2.4.9 Perspective Warp

Tags: c++, opencv, warp

I have the following two images. I am wanting to warp im1 into the plane of im2, ie. im2 is the target plane.

[image: im1] [image: im2]

So, I compute the homography between sparse matching points

```
cv::Mat H = cv::findHomography(matPt1, matPt2, CV_RANSAC );
cv::Mat xxim = im1.clone();
cv::warpPerspective(im1, xxim, H, cv::Size(im2.rows, im2.cols) );
imshow( "xxim", xxim );
```

I had expected to see something like :
[image: expected warp]

However, I see :
[image]

I would also like to mention that this code worked fine when I had OpenCV2.2. However recently I upgraded my opencv to 2.4.9 and now it is causing trouble.

Comment: did your try whether the computed homographies in 2.2 and 2.49 are identical/similar? looks like a broken homography ;)

Comment: unfortunately, I no more have access to 2.2 now. Still any clue about what could be the possible problem and how to fix it?

Comment: wrong/bad features extracted or wrong matches between features. maybe parameter dimensions changed? did you try to display features an matches?